# Replace NULL with some other message in pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to put 'NA' instead of null in else block.
Any way of doing that ?

```
select @query = coalesce(@query, '') + 
          N',max(case when A.[Date] = ''' + 
          cast(cte.startdate as nvarchar(20)) + 
          N''' then A.Attendance end) ' + 
          quotename(convert(char(6), cte.startdate,106))
```

Comment: I see neither an else block nor the word null.

Comment: case when A.[Date] is returning NULL if it doesn't match with A.[Attendance].
Case when A.[Date] = ''' + cast(cte.startdate as nvarchar(20)) + 
N''' then A.Attendance ELSE ?? end) '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do it *after* the `max()`.  So I think you want:

```
coalesce(max(case when A.[Date] = @Date then A.Attendance end), 'N/A')
```

This assumes that `Attendance` is a string.  Otherwise, you have a type error.

I should also note that embedding values in SQL strings is definitely not a good practice.  You should be using parameters.  In SQL Server, you would do so by using `exec sp_executesql` rather than just `exec`.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: What do you think you should do about that?